# My friend says my method is useless, could someone please explain why?

Tags: java, oop, hashmap, wrapper, utilities

I recently gave my source code to my friend so he could look over it and tell me if I have any major errors like memory-leaks, non thread-safe methods used in other `Threads` etc...

And he saw my `HashmapWrapper` class and told me that it was in-efficient, useless and a waste of space. I would really like to know why that is and if what he says is true.

The `HashmapWrapper` class:

```
public class HashmapWrapper<K, V>
{
    public HashMap<K, V> wrapped;

    public HashMapWrapper()
    {
        this.wrapped = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    public HashmapWrapper<K, V> put(K key, V value)
    {
        this.wrapped.put(key, value);
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    public HashMap<K, V> get()
    {
        return this.wrapped;
    }
}
```

It's a very simple class and it's only used to condense any code where I make hashmaps and then put values to them.

Here are some examples where I use the HashmapWrapper:

```
settings.save(new HashmapWrapper<String, String>().put("volume", this.volume.getString()).put("res", this.screen.resolution.getString()).put("music", this.soundSystem.isMusicAllowed().getString()).put("font", this.font.getFontName()).get());

set(new HashmapWrapper<String, Integer>().put("coord.x", this.entity.xCoord).put("", this.entity.yCoord).get());
```

Comment: your friend is right!

Comment: does it provide any more functionality on top of the existing HashMap? If this is it, why not just use a Hashmap?

Comment: I agree with your friend: I see no value in this class whatsoever.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Memory leak? In Java? Quite difficult to have unless playing with classloaders.

Comment: The only value I see is that the `put()` method returns the HashMapWrapped instead of the given value, which allows you to string `put()`s together.

Comment: If all you want to do is to define a `Map` with a fluent/builder syntax, consider Google Guava's `ImmutableMap.builder()` and/or `ImmutableMap.of()` methods.

Comment: The real rason why I use this is so I can string `put()`'s together so I can create a hashmap easily.

Comment: Rename it HashMapBuilder and you're fine.

Comment: @jtahlborn I guess I could do that, or I could just use `Double brace initialization` with a `Hashmap` and put to it.

Comment: ew, don't use double brace init, that's awful.  builders are an accepted coding style.  and experienced coders generally consider them very useful/convenient.  the name "wrapper" makes it seems like the class will live for an extended period of time, in which case it would be useless.  but, "builder" implies it is a convenience for initialization, which is perfectly acceptable and useful.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it's useless -- it does provide a convenient syntax for initializing a map -- but if you're just looking to save some typing on initialization, another way to achieve what you want is to use [double brace initialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization), which would look like this:

```
settings.save(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("volume", this.volume.getString());
    put("res", this.screen.resolution.getString());
    put("music", this.soundSystem.isMusicAllowed().getString());
    put("font", this.font.getFontName()).get());
}});
```

An advantage of doing it this way is that you're still dealing with a subclass of `Map` and not a custom class.

Comment: A disadvantage is that you're creating a separate class to initialize a single object.

Comment: @resueman Agreed, if you use this technique liberally you'll bloat the number of classes generated by the compiler.  Along with that, chances are the person who has to maintain your code will have no idea what it means.

Comment: Not to mention it has implications for serialization.  blech.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your thinking; you want to make method chaining possible. But let me just ask you something. What is easier to read?

```
Map<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

myHashMap.put("This", "Is");
myHashMap.put("Some", "text");
```

Instantly, we know what this does. You're adding two new entries to your `HashMap`.

```
myHashMap.put("This", "is").put("Some", "text");
```

It looks like I'm doing something with the value I just put in, doesn't it? Java has a convention and a standardized syntax, and a lot of the time that doesn't include method chaining with native `Java` objects. It's best to stick with the convention because the next guy is going to say..

*What in the dancing f@!k is this?*, when they're trying to wonder why your `HashMap` implements method chaining. Convention is not only to make your code more fluid; it's there to give the next guy an easier time of understanding the code that they're looking at.

**Edit**

Often, when you've got one very long line of code, it is common practise to carve it up into several lines to make it easier to read. A great example is when you're executing SQL:

```
db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM OTHERTABLE WHERE ID = ?");
```

A little long, so let's format it a little.

```
db.executeQuery("SELECT * 
                 FROM TABLE
                 WHERE ID IN (
                              SELECT ID
                              FROM OTHERTABLE
                              WHERE ID = ?");
```

Instantly, it's obvious you've got a nested SQL query.. Okay, let's follow the same idea with your code.

```
myMap.put("Hello", "there").put("my", "friend").put("this", "is").put("a", "really").put("long", "hashmap").put("entry", "and").put("gee", "this").put("line", "is").put("long", "!");
```

So, what do you do? Oh yeah, carve it up into different lines.

```
myMap.put("Hello", "there")
     .put("my", "friend")
     .put("this", "is")
     .put("a", "really")
     .put("long", "hashmap")
     .put("entry", "and")
     .put("gee", "this")
     .put("line", "is")
     .put("long", "!");
```

Ahh, readable. Alas, you've saved absolutely no space and you're back to square one! Method chaining is nice for a lot of different applications, but when it becomes longer and longer it fades into obscurity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will stick to using a simple Hashmap and just putting to it, the only reason I wanted to use the chaining is so I don't have to make my code have more lines when it could just have one :)

Comment: Hmm.. let me show you an edit.

Comment: Another thing, is that this code will never be given to anyone else and it will only ever be used for private use, and if it is in a public program, the source code probably won't be released. Then again, if the source code is released I will definitely add some documentation so the next guy doesn't think `What in the dancing f@!k is this?`

Answer (score -1):

The reason your friend says the class is useless is because your wrapper doesn't add any substantial new functionality to a hashmap. The only thing your put method adds is the ability to chain put(k,v) commands which does not follow normal java style. Chaining commands tends to make code less readable and harder to debug/maintain.

If you want to be able to put multiple key value pairs into your hashmap in one line, a better way would be creating a method. Something similar to this.

`public void put(Hashmap<k,v> map, k[] keys, v[] values){
    if (k.size() != v.size()){
        //throw error
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < k.size(); i++){
            map.put(k[i], v[i]);
        }`

Obviously you could adjust how the method takes arguments. A two dimensional array would be another option, or just use the hashmap put method if you don't have to do this very often. Ultimately it's up to you.

Comment: actually, the builder pattern is considered quite useful and convenient in the right contexts.

Comment: just because the original jdk apis don't use it doesn't make it a bad thing.  there are many mistakes in the original apis (or, if not mistakes, "learning opportunities").  if you look at the jdk 8 stream api, you will see heavy use of the builder pattern.

Comment: @jtahlborn I know there are cases where the builder pattern can be useful. I was simply referencing general java conventions which tend to avoid chaining commands as the original wrapper class allowed.

Comment: @jtahlborn I agree it isn't always a bad thing. I was just answering why I thought his friend would find his wrapper pointless, and pointing out the same thing christopher did in his answer, that method chaining can reduce readability.

Comment: your answer says "chain put(k,v) commands which is not considered good practice in java".  i was responding to that.  if that is not what you think, then you should clarify your answer...

Comment: @jtahlborn Thank you for clarifying, and you are indeed correct. My wording was misleading and needed a fix. Hopefully this is a little more accurate and better. Thanks too for the correction. If my answer still isn't well worded please let me know so I can improve upon it.

Comment: well, i'm not a fan of the example util method either.  i don't see that as any more convenient or better.